# Learning LWJGL Game creation?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I would like to learn LWJGL, but I've been having a hard time locating any good tutorials.

I've been trying to find tutorials on creating the actual game objects. I've pretty much figured out how to use the keyboard and mouse functions of LWJGL, and have a black window created. Any links or code examples would be much appreciated.

I realize that what I have is not very much.

Here is what I have so far:

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        //Render


        if(kh.checkForExit())
        {
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        kh.setMAINFRAMEB(true);
        int x = Mouse.getX();
        int y = -Mouse.getY();

        Display.setTitle(new String("Zontreck - Escape to quit - " + x + ", " + y));

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                String dat = sh.readSave();
            }
        }
        );

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
```

(kh) is my Keyboard event handler.

(sh) is my SaveHandler class.

UPDATE:

How do I generate a map randomly of different objects? The map would also then be saved to a file on the computer to allow play later. How do I create the player object (If for a multiplayer game)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random objects:

I think you will need to use the Java's random number generator for this one. 
First, you will need to decide how many objects do you want to put in the level (because we will set a range for the random number generator). 
But before that, you will need to put every object's drawing in separated functions, like that:

```java
public void drawChair() {
   //drawing
}

public void drawTV() {
   //drawing
}
```

So, after that, you can generate some random numbers:

```java
Random r = new Random();
int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100-1) + 1; // we will have 100 objects 

switch(randomNumber) {
    case 1:
        drawChair();
        break;
    case 2:
        drawTV();
        break;
    ...
    case 100: 
        drawSofa();
        break;
}
```

From now, with this little random number generation, objects are going to be generated randomly.

Saving:

For this, see this tutorial:

```
 http://youtu.be/7G_xtkvyleM?t=25m3s
```

Player object:

Maybe I'm not right, but you can do this easily, if you put the character drawing on a separated function, like drawCharacter(); So, if a player joins, you just need to call this drawCharacter();

I hope I helped you a bit, good luck with the LWJGL.

Comment: Thank you, I do realize I should've been more specific. It was late when I submitted the question... I was tired. I'm updating the question.